# I installed IE 64bit from this site, now I'm running IE9 and can't get rid of IE 64bit, help!

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-8, uninstall, internet-explorer-9

I found this site when I upgraded my desktop pc to 64bit from the 32bit it came installed with. I then downloaded windows 8 for 64bit at the time, and found it caused me more problems than it did help! Now that I'm running IE9 as my default browser on both pc's on my home network, I'd like to uninstall IE8, 64bit, but can't seem to figure out how. I [after reading some of the posts and questions on here] was under the impression that when I upgraded to IE9 and IE8 was uninstalled my 64bit IE8 should have been uninstalled as well, but that didn't happen! What can I do now to fix this?

Comment: Windows 8 is still testing software...you may want to do a fresh install of everything

Comment: You cannot uninstall IE8 64-bit, there is no reason to do so, simply stop using the 64-bit shortcut.  Windows 8 Dev has IE10 not IE9 so what exactly have you installed, feel free to edit your question, so what you did is clear.

Comment: Hope this helps-http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700